# Jackson: deserialize custom attributes in XML to POJO

Tags: java, xml, jackson, deserialization, pojo

I would like to deserialize and map to class following values by name attribute. 
This is piece of my XML file.

```
                <custom-attributes>
                    <custom-attribute name="Name1" dt:dt="string">VALUE</custom-attribute>
                    <custom-attribute name="Name2" dt:dt="string"> 
                        <value>1111</value>
                        <value>1111</value>
                        <value>1111</value>
                    </custom-attribute>
                    <custom-attribute name="Name3" dt:dt="string">VALUE2</custom-attribute>
                    <custom-attribute dt:dt="boolean" name="Name3">VALUE3</custom-attribute> 
                    <custom-attribute dt:dt="boolean" name="Name4">VALUE4</custom-attribute>
                </custom-attributes>
```

And This is piece of my pojo class

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class CustomAttributes {

     @JacksonXmlProperty(localName="name3", isAttribute = true)
     private String roleID;

     public String getRoleID() {
           return roleID;
      }

     public void setRoleID(String roleID) {
          this.roleID = roleID;
}
```

}

Do you know ho to properly read values from those attribues by name ?  Currently im receiving null

Comment: How does you deserialization code look like?

Comment: CLASS deserializedData = xmlMapper.readValue(xmlContent, CLASS.class); works for other classes but i have just pro blem with that Custom attributes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what the result is supposed to look like, but if you want 
to parse the complete xml into matching objects they would look like this:

```
public class CustomAttributeList {

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "custom-attributes")
    private List<CustomAttributes> list;

    ...
}
```

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "custom-attribute")
public class CustomAttributes {

    // the name attribute
    @JacksonXmlProperty
    private String name;

    // the datatype from the dt:dt field
    @JacksonXmlProperty(namespace = "dt")
    private String dt;

    // the content between the tags (if available)
    @JacksonXmlText
    private String content;

    // the values in the content (if available)
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "value")
    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
    private List<String> values;

    ...
}
```

Note that the `localName="name3"` from your question is not referring to a property at all.